# Keep the rows with the latest version. See example - R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`, it is in this format:

| id | version | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | v02_abc_1 | 1 | `NA` |
| A0002 | v01_abc_1 | `NA` | 0 |
| A0002 | v02_abc_1 | 0 | `NA` |
| A0002 | v03_abc_1 | 0 | 1 |
| A0003 | v01_abc_1 | `NA` | 1 |

How do I transform it into:

| id | version | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | v02_abc_1 | 1 | `NA` |
| A0002 | v03_abc_1 | 0 | 1 |
| A0003 | v01_abc_1 | `NA` | 1 |

Where the row with the latest version for each `id` is kept and the rest are removed? NOT all `id`s have three versions; some have two, and some have only one version.

Assume that the data has hundreds of rows.

Comment: It is not discovered in the question what format of version is that makes it consider earlier or later than another

Comment: From latest to oldest: `v03_abc_1`,`v02_abc_1`, `v01_abc_1`

Comment: I mean for instance what `abc` is. `v01_Nov_1`  is less than `v01_Oct_1` if we sort them in alphabetical order

Comment: All records have `abc`, I would've mentioned otherwise. Thanks for the note though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(id, version) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  id    version   column_3 column_4
  <chr> <chr>        <int>    <int>
1 A0001 v02_abc_1        1       NA
2 A0002 v03_abc_1        0        1
3 A0003 v01_abc_1       NA        1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("A0001", "A0002", "A0002", "A0002", "A0003"
), version = c("v02_abc_1", "v01_abc_1", "v02_abc_1", "v03_abc_1", 
"v01_abc_1"), column_3 = c(1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA), column_4 = c(NA, 
0L, NA, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the last row per group using `slice_max` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = version, n = 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>   id    version   column_3 column_4
#>   <chr> <chr>        <int>    <int>
#> 1 A0001 v02_abc_1        1       NA
#> 2 A0002 v03_abc_1        0        1
#> 3 A0003 v01_abc_1       NA        1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "id version column_3    column_4
A0001   v02_abc_1   1   NA
A0002   v01_abc_1   NA  0
A0002   v02_abc_1   0   NA
A0002   v03_abc_1   0   1
A0003   v01_abc_1   NA  1
", header = TRUE)
```